# How do I get PortfolioItem results in Rally SDK1.33?

Tags: rally

I am using the Rally SDK1.33 as in the end I need to display information using the LoginKey outside of Rally. I am trying to query information on PortfolioItem, but it looks like no results are being returned. - However if I put the query in the through the webservice doc pages, I get a result.

Using the following link (replacing 123456789 with a real ObjectID for a PortfolioItem and the workspace 987654321 with a real workspace) I get back the PortfolioItem object:

[https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.43/portfolioitem.js?workspace=https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.43/workspace/987654321&query=(ObjectID%20%3D%20123456789)&fetch=true&start=1&pagesize=20](https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.43/portfolioitem.js?workspace=https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.43/workspace/987654321&query=%28ObjectID%20%3D%20123456789%29&fetch=true&start=1&pagesize=20)

However if I try to query it from code, I get back the query results without any results and without any errors (again - using a real PortfolioItem ObjectID instead of the 123456789).

ExternalPortfolio

```
<!--App information-->
<meta name="Name" content="App: ExternalPortfolio"/>
<meta name="Version" content="1.0"/>
<meta name="Vendor" content=""/>

<!--Include SDK-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://rally1.rallydev.com/apps/1.33/sdk.js?debug=true&apiVersion=1.43"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">

    function onLoad() {
        rallyDataSource = new rally.sdk.data.RallyDataSource('__WORKSPACE_OID__', 
                                                  '__PROJECT_OID__',
                                                   '__PROJECT_SCOPING_UP__', 
                                                  '__PROJECT_SCOPING_DOWN__');

        var objectId = 123456789;

        var queryConfig = { 
                type: 'PortfolioItem',
                key: 'portfolio',
                fetch: 'FormattedID,Name',
                query: '(ObjectID = ' + objectId +')'
               };

        rallyDataSource.findAll(queryConfig, showPortfolio, errorCallBack);  

        function showPortfolio(results) {
            console.log(results);
        }

        function errorCallBack(response) {
        console.log('Got problems!')
        console.log(response.Errors);
        console.log(response.Warnings);
        }   
    }

    rally.addOnLoad(onLoad);


</script>

<style type="text/css">

    .externalPortfolio {
        /* Add app styles here */
    }

</style>
```

I have created a number of reports on Stories and Defects (most all running outside of Rally), but never for a PortfolioItem. - Am I missing something here? Or is there a severe bug with the v1.xx SDK or v1.x API in handling portfolio items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be the issue you're encountering, but if you're running outside Rally, try setting *both* the Workspace OID and Project OID:

```
    rallyDataSource = new rally.sdk.data.RallyDataSource(
                                              '12345678910', 
                                              '12345678911',
                                              '__PROJECT_SCOPING_UP__', 
                                              '__PROJECT_SCOPING_DOWN__');
```

When I initially ran your example using Workspace OID only, I found that like you I was not receiving any results, and no errors were returned. However, examining the generated query URL in Chrome's network console:

`https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.43/adhoc.js?_method=POST&adHocQuery={"portfolio":"/portfolioitem?query=(ObjectID = \"152345647\")&pagesize=200&fetch=FormattedID,Name&workspace=/workspace/12345678910&project=${/user/userprofile/defaultProject}&projectScopeUp=false&projectScopeDown=true"}&jsonp=dojo.io.script.jsonp_dojoIoScript1._jsonpCallback`

You can see that the User's default project is being passed as the Project parameter. However the PI with that specific ObjectID was in a different Workspace. As an outcome, I was receiving the following error:

```
{
    portfolio: {
        _rallyAPIMajor: "1",
        _rallyAPIMinor: "43",
        Errors: [
            "The specified project must be in the specified workspace. Project OID=12345678921 is in Workspace OID=1234569840 and the specified Workspace is OID=12345678910."
        ],
        Warnings: [ ],
        _ref: "/portfolioitem?query=(ObjectID = "152345647")&pagesize=200&fetch=FormattedID,Name&workspace=/workspace/12345678910&project=/project/12345678921&projectScopeUp=false&projectScopeDown=true",
        TotalResultCount: 0,
        StartIndex: 0,
        PageSize: 0,
        Results: [ ]
    }
}
```

Once I included the Project OID in the new-up of `rallyDataSource` instead of the hangman, I obtained the expected result in the console:

```
Object {errors: Array[0], warnings: Array[0], portfolio: Array[1]}
errors: Array[0]
portfolio: Array[1]
0: Object
DirectChildrenCount: 0
FormattedID: "F10"
Name: "PI Feature 10"
_objectVersion: "7"
_rallyAPIMajor: "1"
_rallyAPIMinor: "43"
_ref: "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.43/portfolioitem/feature/152345647.js"
_refObjectName: "PI Feature 10"
_type: "PortfolioItem/Feature"
__proto__: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array[0]
warnings: Array[0]
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: Thanks! - Is this only the way that PortfolioItems work? When working with HierarchicalRequirements and Defects the hangman variables always resolve to the default workspace/project.

Comment: To be honest I'm not sure. The adhoc endpoint used by WSAPI 1.x was never designed to handle PIs. While it can be used to access them, it's clunky. WSAPI 2.0 and AppSDK 2 are the way to go for PIs with Rally Javascript. However I understand the lack of login key functionality with SDK2 is limiting for that.

Comment: Thanks Mark! Aside from upvoting LoginKey functionality for SDK2 on the ideas.rallydev.com, if there is anything else I can do to help push for it (and soon), please please please (!!!) let me know. I would love to use SDK2, but until it supports external reports it is a non-starter at my company for anyone to learn it or use it (even if they think the reports will only be used inside Rally - since eventually someone will want them outside of Rally).

Comment: Shawn thank you for the feedback. While AppSDK2 LoginKey is currently not on the product roadmap, it's in-demand enough that there's a movement going to do a hack-a-thon focused on that. If anything comes to fruition from that, I'll post a comment back here!